# How to find max value in each row of matrix w/o max function?

Tags: matlab

In MATLAB, if I have:

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5; 4 8 9 10];
[N M] = size(A);
c = zeros(N,1);
for n=1:N;
    for m=1:M;
        c(n) = ?;
    end
end
```

What do I replace ? with that will find the maximum value in each row of A without using the max function?

Comment: Do you know how to find the maximum value for a 1-D array?

Comment: and why would you want to do that for?

Comment: @Eitan, No, I do not.  Algorithmically I become confused.

Comment: @Shai, I believe that is my business.  You don't have to respond if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1 2 3 4; 2 3 4 5; 4 8 9 10];
[N M] = size(A);
c = A(:,1); % modified per Eitan's suggestion
for n=1:N;
    % c(n) = A(n,1); % commented out per Eitan's suggestion.
    for m=1:M;
        c(n) = (c(n)<A(n,m))*A(n,m) + (c(n)>=A(n,m))*c(n);
    end
end
```

Only one of the logical statements will be true, and thus the minimum will either be updated, or stay the same. Super awkward... but thanks to Eitan T, no longer needs an extra line. One would like to make the internal loop start at 2, but not necessary for this code to work (and minimizes the changes needed from the original code given.)

Not sure why you would ever *not* use the `min` function, but I guess you had a reason...

Comment: Why would you insert the additional line `c(n) = A(n, 1)` instead simply of initializing `c` to `A(:, 1)`?

Comment: @EitanT I was trying to mirror the code of OP as closely as possible; but agree that your tweak is perfectly valid and circumvents the extra line. Updated the answer accordingly.